# How to enable Crashlytics in Xcode 14, if console is not logging anything about Crashlytics, after following steps in documentation

Tags: swift, firebase, analytics, crashlytics, xcode14

I was trying to make Crashlytics and Analytics working for days, nothing worked. I even reinstalled Xcode 14. I followed the steps in firebase documentations but it was not working.

Comment: Make sure the device is not connected/attached to Xcode

Comment: Enable debug mode in Xcode, run the app and if possible share the output. This can help us see what could be going wrong with the Crashlytics SDK. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#enable-debug-logging

Comment: After much deliberation, I was able to put a fatalError() in my authentication view right after the app launches from Main. not sure why this worked, but it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If:

- You installed Firebase Crashlytics / Analytics  by pods, Your Xcode version is 14 or above ,
- All steps in official documentations doesn't work for you,
- If you didn't use Crashlytics/Analytics with your app in older Xcode (13 and below) versions with dSYM
- If you trying to find and upload your dSYM manually and upload to firebase

Maybe problem is not about dSYM at all, like my issue. Try this :

Open your target's build settings. Search for "Other Linker Flags". When you find it, add this line to release and debug sections

"$(inherited)"

like this : [image]

Most of the replies to this issue in different places are about how Xcode 14 doesn't create dSYM in organizer, how AppStore TestFlight doesn't have the option to download dSYM anymore. But it was something else. This fixed my problem entirely, maybe it can help you too.